# Expected an array

Tags: php, symfony

I have a script to add and edit users, adding works fine but the edit page shows me this error:

**Expected an array.**
500 Internal Server Error - TransformationFailedException

**UserType.php**

```
namespace Store\UserBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class UserType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('username', 'text')
        ->add('password', 'text')
        ->add('salt', 'text', array('required' => false))
        ->add('roles', 'choice', array(
        'choices'  => array(
            'ROLE_ADMIN'      => 'ROLE_ADMIN',
            'ROLE_USER'       => 'ROLE_USER',
            'ROLE_AUTEUR'     => 'ROLE_AUTEUR',
            'ROLE_MODERATEUR' => 'ROLE_MODERATEUR',
                ),
        'required'    => false,
        'empty_value' => 'Choisissez un ou plusieurs roles',
        'empty_data'  => null,
        'multiple' => true,
        'expanded' => false,
        ));
}   

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'Store\UserBundle\Entity\User'
    ));
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'store_userbundle_user';
}
}
```

**UserEditType.php**

```
<?php

namespace Store\UserBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType; 
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class UserEditType extends UserType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    parent::buildForm($builder, $options) ;
    $builder->remove('roles') ;
}   

public function getName()
{
    return 'store_userbundle_useredit';
}
}
```

**Controller**

```
<?php
//...

// modifier
public function modifierAction(User $user)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager() ;

    $form = $this->createForm(new UserEditType, $user) ;

    $request = $this->get('request');
    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST')
    {
        $form->bind($request) ;
        if ($form->isValid())
        {
            $em->flush();

            $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('info', 'User bien modifie');

            return $this->redirect( $this->generateUrl('store_produit_index') );
        }
    }

    return $this->render('StoreUserBundle:Security:modifier.html.twig',
    array(
        'form' => $form->createView() ,
        ));
}

//..

?>
```

**form.html.twig**

```
<div class="well">
<form action="" method="post" {{ form_enctype(form) }}>
    <span style="color:red">{{ form_errors(form) }}</span>

        {{ form_widget(form) }}

    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
</form>
</div>
```

If I add **$builder-> remove ('roles');** in UserEditType.php , it works but without changing roles in database.

**User.php**

```
<?php

namespace Store\UserBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
* User
*
* @ORM\Table()
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Store\UserBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
*/
class User implements UserInterface
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
 */
private $username;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $password;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="salt", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $salt;

/**
 * @var array
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="roles", type="array")
 */
private $roles;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->roles = array();
}

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set username
 *
 * @param string $username
 * @return User
 */
public function setUsername($username)
{
    $this->username = $username;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get username
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getUsername()
{
    return $this->username;
}

/**
 * Set password
 *
 * @param string $password
 * @return User
 */
public function setPassword($password)
{
    $this->password = $password;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get password
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getPassword()
{
    return $this->password;
}

/**
 * Set salt
 *
 * @param string $salt
 * @return User
 */
public function setSalt($salt)
{
    $this->salt = $salt;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get salt
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getSalt()
{
    return $this->salt;
}

/**
 * Set roles
 *
 * @param array $roles
 * @return User
 */
public function setRoles($roles)
{
    $this->roles = $roles;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get roles
 *
 * @return array 
 */
public function getRoles()
{
    return $this->roles;
}

public function eraseCredentials()
{
}

}
```

Comment: could you show us your User entity ?

Comment: I have no permission to add another question

Comment: Try restarting your server.

Comment: I have edited the question, you can show User entity in the end

Answer (score 1):

Could you try to unserialize the returned value of getRoles ?

```
/**
 * Get roles
 *
 * @return array 
 */
public function getRoles()
{
    return unserialize($this->roles);
}
```

Comment: ContextErrorException: Notice: unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Error at offset 0 of 11 bytes in D:\wamp\www\Symfony2\src\Store\UserBundle\Entity\User.php line 157

Comment: What is the content of the "roles" field in your database ?

Comment: Yes, I have just tried to add and edit another user, with content ' a:2:{i:0;s:9:"ROLE_USER";i:1;s:11:"ROLE_AUTEUR";} ' and it works now.

Comment: thank you, thanks to your question I discovered that there is an error in the content of the "roles" field in database.

Answer (score 0):

Form class is expecting that entity will return an array because you are using multiple choices. use type array in .orm file and generate entity again and update schema. Like

```
roles:
    type: array
```